# Rails, conditional including Javascript if not loaded?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am trying to include a Javascript file in my Rails layout only if it hasn't been loaded from a CDN, for example in pure Javascript I would do the following;

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.Modernizr || document.write('<script src="assets/js/modernizr.2.6.2.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

How would I go about this working using the Rails asset pipeline?

I tried this out,

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.Modernizr || document.write('<%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr-2.6.2" %>');
</script>
```

But this is written out as,

```
<script>
        window.Modernizr || document.write('<script src="/assets/modernizr-2.6.2.js?body=1"></script>
```

Which then somehow gets into my body HTML and leaves, `"');"` in my body tag. So the tag isn't closed properly.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, the example won't work because Rails is already done parsing the template by the time you get to writing the javascript-include-tag in the document. What happens if you use your original script (the first example) does it do what you need?

Comment: It's more that it's a hardcoded path to an asset, which seems dangerous.

Comment: Hmm, yes re-looking at your example of output - it does look like it's doing something odd. What you want is the tag... but encoded so the backslash isn't a real slash? have you looked at the raw html, or are you looking at it with firebug (or equiv)?  (your browser may be "helping" with the interpretation here... not that it's going to work either way... but it'd be good to be certain we're clear on what's popping out of rails' javascript tag. Is there a way of storing the string somewhere previously and escaping it at this point?... just speculating.

Comment: also - perhaps rather than using javascript_include_tag you could just use javascript_path and make your own script-tag: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_path

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired output use the [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) helper.

To use your example:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.Modernizr || document.write('<%= j(javascript_include_tag("modernizr-2.6.2")) %>');
</script>
```

`j()` is an alias of `escape_javascript()` and looks neater.

Hope this helps.